# remove a string and prepend a string to every index of a large file

Tags: perl, sed

I have a large file with many many indices of the form:

```
./7002/blah/blah/blah.xml
```

I want to modify them all such that I remove the initial `./`, i.e.

```
7002/blah/blah/blah.xml
```

Then I want to prepend the string `../input/test_input/`, so the final result would look like:

```
../input/test_input/7002/blah/blah/blah.xml
```

for each index.

How can I achieve this with one command?

Is it best to use `sed` for this task?

Although there are questions and answers about both these operations I've not seen any about synthesizing both operations with one command.

---

**UPDATE**

Additionally, since some of the indices in the file I am trying to process are the names of the symlinks, is there a way to quickly remove anything that doesn't conform to the format: `../input/test_input/7002/blah/blah/blah.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sed.

```
sed 's~^\./~../input/test_input/~' file
```

You could also use the same expression in perl along with `-pe` parameter.

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/LZ65sE)

Comment: some of the indices in that file are the names of the symlinks, which is now messing up my program. is there a way to quickly remove anything that doesn't conform to the format `../input/test_input/7002/blah/blah/blah.xml`